# Python Error:sheet attribute has no column ncolumns

Tags: python, xlrd

I am learning python on my own ,and trying to search a given text,
however i am struck up with this error ,tried to google and solve on my own but of no use.
This is my code .

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("TC0132_Shooting_Information_Display(OSD_List)_DMHH.xlsm" , "rb")
print book.nsheets
print book.sheet_names()
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
# print first_sheet.row_values(10)
cell = first_sheet.cell(10 ,10)
print cell
# print cell.value

print first_sheet.row_slice(rowx=9,start_colx=2,end_colx=10)

for i in range(first_sheet.nrows):
    row = first_sheet.row_values(10)
    for j in range (first_sheet.ncolumns):
        column == first_sheet.column_values(5)
        if row[column] == search_value:
            print i,j
    print 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `ncolumns` a typo? Your error means that `first_sheet` either doesn't have an `ncolumns` method or else that it's not the object you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such attribute as ncolumns:
You have a typo:

```
for j in range (first_sheet.ncols):
```

instead of

```
for j in range (first_sheet.ncolumns):
```

Comment: Please point out this typo if you think it's the problem. Just posting code with no explanation is rarely helpful.

Comment: I don't understand a down-vote here? @SuperBiasedMan

Comment: I didn't leave the downvote, but I suspect that it was either because questions caused by typos are supposed to be flagged for closure or they might have seen a one line code answer and assumed it wasn't sufficient.